# Updating my textArea whilst in a while loop

Tags: java

I'm using Java to create a UDP peer to peer chat program.

Without this while loop my textArea

```
    while(true)
    {
        DatagramPacket incoming = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
        try {
            serverSocket.receive(incoming);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        String incomingMessage = new String (incoming.getData());
        textArea.setText("Client: " + incomingMessage);
        System.out.println(incomingMessage);
        textArea.setText("Client: " + incomingMessage);
    }
```

With the while loop my textArea doe not update, I've tried using an invoke in there:

```
                    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() { public void run() {
                    try {
                          textArea.append(msg);
```

But it didn't seem to work still.

I'm using Eclipse Luna window core builder and it automatically made this automated code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Server window = new Server();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

This is a the automated code that was written, and by looking at the API, this updates the GUI every so often depending on events.

However, it can't update in the while loop since there is no event.

How can I fix this, thank you.

Comment: Run the while(true) in a separate thread and in the logic wrap the textArea changes in SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait()

Comment: "I can see You are working just with a thread and that thread is blocking because your process does not sleep. Try sleep the process for a while or work with more than one thread." by [@maframaran](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4405606/maframaran)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to respect Swing threading rules which to summarize too briefly means that all running tasks, such as waiting for and capturing your data, should be done in a background thread, and all Swing calls should be done on the Swing event thread. Use a `SwingWorker<Void, String>` to help you do this.

Please check out [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) to see a tutorial with all the gory details.

e.g.,

```
private class MySwingWorker extends SwingWorker<Void, String> {
  private byte[] buffer = new byte[2000];

  @Override
  protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
     while (true) {
        DatagramPacket incoming = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
        serverSocket.receive(incoming);

        String incomingMessage = new String(incoming.getData());
        publish(incomingMessage);
     }
     return null;
  }

  @Override
  protected void process(List<String> chunks) {
     for (String chunk : chunks) {
        textArea.append("Client: " + chunk + "\n");
     }
  }
}
```

Other suggestions:

- You call `execute()` on the SwingWorker to run it.
- I almost always add a PropertyChangeListener to my worker before executing it.
- In this listener I watch for the newValue to be SwingWorker.StateValue.DONE.
- When I encounter this, I call `get()` on my SwingWorker, even if it returns Void. This is to help me trap and respond to any exceptions that might have occurred within the SwingWorker as it was running.

Comment: Thank you, sorry I've never done GUI with Java, so never knew there were rules such as what threads can do what. Nicely explained! 

Going to use a the Swing Worker class!

Answer (score 2):

*With the while loop my textArea doe not update*

Most likely you started your loop on the [EDT (Event Dispatching Thread)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html). This prevents the UI from updating itself.
Try instead to run your code in another Thread. `SwingWorker` can be one option, creating your own Thread or ThreadPool mechanism (Executors service) is another solution. Just make sure that all your updates to the UI are performed in the EDT (for example by moving them in an `EventQueue.invokeLater` block)

See also this link that provides an example on how to use correctly a [`SwingWorker`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/interim.html)